# Not able to get the login to work for project

Tags: batch-file

I am not able to get the login to work, I am able to store the username and password in to an folder called "RootData" and then I am able to store the username and password in to an .dll file (I think).

```
    set /p userName="user name?: "
    set /p userNameConfim="confirm user name: "
    if "%userName%" equ "%userNameConfim%" (
    echo %userNameConfim% >> RootData\ProgramData.dll
    )else(
    echo something went wrong kek
    )
```

But here it goes wrong, (i think)

```
    :login
    :begin
    set usr=
    set /p usr=Enter your username: 
    if {%usr%}=={} goto :begin
    set authenticated=
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (RootData\ProgramData.dll) do (
    if {%%a}=={%usr%} set authenticated=true)
    if not defined authenticated (
    echo Invalid Username & goto :begin
    )
```

full code:

> https://gist.github.com/Occisio/bbe4f9e568c0c627f43f7da051185f22

Not sure why.

Comment: `)else(` must read `) else (`...

Comment: @TripeHound, there is no variable set *and* read in the same block of code, so delayed expansion is not necessary; if you are talking about `if defined` (which is a new block of code here), this works even in the same block of code...

Comment: Do not overwrite an important system variable, change it from `%userName%`.

Comment: @aschipfl No, I was mainly mis-parsing the (not well laid out) code. Will delete my comment (although I didn't realise `if defined` will work even in the same block of code... so either way I was wrong!)

Comment: Also it should be `)else (` or `) else (`, not `)else(`, you should use case insnsitivity ,`/I`,  in your `If` commands and doublequote strings and `Set` commands properly, `Set /P "usr=Enter your username: "` and undefine variables before setting them through input prompts. It is important to note that users can input nothing or anything at the input prompt, so do not continue your code without fully verifying their input first.

Comment: Thanks for all the feed back, I am taking all the tips and suggestions. 
The code actually works now after re-parsing and well fixing very crappy code structure. 

I am very new to this, thanks for helping me out :D!